# Could you please explain how to solve following problem?

Tags: npgsql

```
 // Verbinndung zum SQL-Server aufbauen
                NpgsqlConnection SqlConn = new NpgsqlConnection(Program.Data.Settings.SQL_Server_ConnectionString);
                SqlConn.Open();

               NpgsqlDataAdapter daSql = new NpgsqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + Program.Data.Tab_SinterPersonal, SqlConn);

                 NpgsqlCommandBuilder cmds = new  NpgsqlCommandBuilder(daSql);

                daSql.DeleteCommand = cmds.GetDeleteCommand(); 
                daSql.InsertCommand = cmds.GetInsertCommand(); 
                daSql.UpdateCommand = cmds.GetUpdateCommand(); 

                daSql.Update(Program.Data.dsSql.Tables[Program.Data.Tab_SinterPersonal]);
                
                //NpgsqlConnection.Commit();      

                SqlConn.Commit();
                SqlConn.Close();
```

Error:

> `NpgsqlConnection` does not contain a definition for `Commit` and no extension method `Commit` accepting a first argument of type `NpgsqlConnection` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commit isn't something that's done on a connection, it's done on a transaction. The code should look like the following:

```cs
using var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(Program.Data.Settings.SQL_Server_ConnectionString);
SqlConn.Open();

using var transaction = conn.BeginTransaction(); // Begin the transaction

var daSql = new NpgsqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + Program.Data.Tab_SinterPersonal, SqlConn);

var cmds = new  NpgsqlCommandBuilder(daSql);

daSql.DeleteCommand = cmds.GetDeleteCommand(); 
daSql.InsertCommand = cmds.GetInsertCommand(); 
daSql.UpdateCommand = cmds.GetUpdateCommand(); 

daSql.Update(Program.Data.dsSql.Tables[Program.Data.Tab_SinterPersonal]);

transaction.Commit(); // Commit the transaction
```